# Windows threads (c run-time, pthreads, std::thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++11, std

Maybe it is incorrect question, but I am trying to link in one picture terms:

- Windows multithreaded C run-time (for example _beginthreadex);
- pthreads;
- std::thread;

Please give me explanation on:

1. These libraries are separate on Windows or they layered under each other?
2. Does pthread use multithreaded C run-time on Windows?
3. Does std::thread use multithreaded C run-time on Windows? Is std::thread realization on Windows wraps WinThreads?

Comment: Do you have a look at std::thread source?

Comment: All CRT and C++ library functions are implemented using OS-specific API. For Windows threading, this is CreateThread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a brief answer, `std::thread` is a higher level abstraction of threading API of the OS. It uses threading WinAPI on Windows, `pthreads` on Linux.